# Work permit and visa for Portugal?

Tags: working-visas, schengen, portugal

I'm a non-EU national, currently residing on a Critical Skills work permit in Ireland, together with my spouse.

A company in Portugal (I'm in IT) is going to make me an offer this week, to relocate there. They are willing to sponsor me for a work permit. I'd just like to check on the process for myself and my wife:

**Step 1:** The company applies for a work permit for me. Does anyone know how long this might take to be approved?

**Step 2:** We need to get visas to land in Portugal from the local Portugese embassy. The thing is - we're from a country whose nationals don't need visas to land in Schengen agreement countries for tourist visits. Would this pertain to our case as well?

**Step 3:** After we land in Portugal, we need to apply for residence permits straight away - I've heard the approval process can last up to 60 days.

Does anyone know more about this? Also, would my wife be able to go to Portugal alone before me, to sort out an apartment (we have some friends there)?